# How do i detect the offset height change of footer to top of browser using jquery

Tags: jquery

My problem started after i started using jquery accordion. Each time the content height change, the footer would climb above the sidebar.I actually have this code in place

```
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height=$("#footer").offset().top;
```

to automatically assign the offset height to the sidebar, but it didn't really help after putting in the accordion.

How can i use jquery to automatically detect the offset height change whenever the accordion moves? Thanks for help.

[Footer climbs above sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ngPq.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ngPq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out myself.

```
$(window).scroll("resize", re_adjustSideBar);

function re_adjustSideBar() {    
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height=$("#footer").offset().top; 
}
```

Thank You